# remove space between list items css

Tags: html, css

This may sound like a dumb question but how would I remove the space between list items on this page for example:

http://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/tales-of-majeyal-now-on-desura.1685

The ul has a class called "content-list".

Setting padding or margin to 0 does nothing it seems.

Answer (score 1):

There are line breaks between those list-items.

Remove the `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

The list on that page has line breaks between each list item, causing the spaces.

Remove the `<br />`'s

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <br />
    <li>Item</li>
    <br />
    <li>Item</li>
    <br />
</ul>
```

Becomes:

```
 <ul>
     <li>Item</li>
     <li>Item</li>
     <li>Item</li>
 </ul>
```

To fix the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<br>`'s between list items. If you are using some kind of web HTML editor - try to edit this code in plain HTML view.